# Using Jersey Client with Apache connector, timeout doesn't work

Tags: java, apache, timeout, jersey-2.0

I'm implementing a Restful client using Jersey Client as follows:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 60000);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

This code has been working OK with the timeout exception thrown properly whenever the request time exceed the defined value. However when I decided to switch to use the ApacheConnector as follow:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();    
clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);       
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);
ApacheConnectorProvider provider = new ApacheConnectorProvider();        
clientConfig.connectorProvider(provider);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 60000);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

The timeout doesn't seem to work anymore so now when the server fails to respond my client will keep waiting until like forever without throwing timeout exception.

Have anyone encountered this problem before or had any clue of what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Did you got answer for your question? I facing same behavior but intermittently..

Answer (score 1):

Try to create and register a `org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig`:

```
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.REQUEST_CONFIG, RequestConfig.custom()
  .setConnectTimeout(60000)
  .setSocketTimeout(60000)
  .build());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RequestConfig reqConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(time_out_value).build();
```